# How to get a button to trigger both methods?

Tags: java, android, button

I'm creating this TicTacToe game in Android Studio and on my onClick method, I would draw an X or O, and also check if someone wins. The problem I have is that when someone is about to play the winning move, it only executes the method for winning and not the method for drawing the X or O, so the game terminates without drawing the last letter

```
public class button1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];
private boolean player1Turn = true;
private int roundCount =0;
private int player1Points =0;
private int player2Points =0;

private TextView textViewPlayer1;
private TextView textViewPlayer2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_button1);
    textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.player1__number_score);
    textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.player2__number_score);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
            buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
            buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    if(!((Button) view).getText().toString().equals("")){
        return;
    }
    if(player1Turn) {
        ((Button) view).setText("X");
    }else{
        ((Button) view).setText("O");

    }
    roundCount++;
    if(checkForWin()){
        if(player1Turn){
            player1Wins();
        }
        else{
            player2Wins();
        }
    } else if(roundCount == 9){
        draw();
    }else{
        player1Turn =!player1Turn;
    }

}
private boolean checkForWin(){
    String[][] check = new String[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            check[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();

        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if (check[i][0].equals(check[i][1]) && check[i][0].equals(check[i][2]) && !check[i][0].equals("")){
            return true;
        }

    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if (check[0][i].equals(check[1][i]) && check[0][i].equals(check[2][i]) && !check[0][i].equals("")){
            return true;
        }

    }
    if (check[0][0].equals(check[1][1]) && check[0][0].equals(check[2][2]) && !check[0][0].equals("")){
        return true;
    }
    if (check[0][2].equals(check[1][1]) && check[0][2].equals(check[2][0]) && !check[0][2].equals("")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private void player1Wins() {
    player1Points++;
    textViewPlayer1.setText(Integer.toString(player1Points));
    Toast.makeText(this,"Player 1 has won",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    resetBoard();

}


private void player2Wins(){
    player2Points++;
    textViewPlayer2.setText(Integer.toString(player2Points));
    Toast.makeText(this,"Player 2 has won",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    resetBoard();

}
private void resetBoard(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            buttons[i][j].setText("");
        }
    }
    roundCount =0;
}
private void draw(){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Draw",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    resetBoard();


}
```

}

Comment: Call `draw()`directly after `if(checkForWin()){`?

Comment: Please add the `checkForWin()` code to your question

Comment: I have added the code to the problem. I'm thinking the problem is that after the last button is pressed the resetBoard method triggers first so it doesn't draw the last character.

Comment: Can you try calling the resetBoard() method with some delay using Handler.postDelayed() method.

Comment: @Vikrant_Dev Thank you so much! It worked perfectly, now I just have to disable all button presses. Could you briefly explain how your solution works? Why doesn't it wait for the delay when I press the button instead of waiting after the button is pressed?